# spring boot: log file not generating

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Using spring boot, deploying on ubuntu tomcat with war

in `application.properties`,

```
logging.path = classpath:/log
```

does not work on local machine or deployed at all. I did check my target/classes/log folder too.
it used to work with

```
logging.path = src/log
```

spring.log would be generated.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`logging.path` needs to be a directory, not a classpath.

This should work:

```
logging.path = /log
```

See this part of the docs for all the legal combinations:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-file-output

Comment: how do I configure it such that a .log file is output on my deployed application?

Comment: you can give it a path to a log location. Something like `logging.path = /log`. I will clarify my answer.

Comment: i did use src/log before, but that doesn't generate any log file either

Comment: `src/log` won't make sense for your deployment. Try `/log`

Comment: tried that, still doesn't work. to clarify, I'm deploying an unzipped war to ROOT folder in tomcat webapps

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't be trying to log to your classpath in the first place.  And it likely doesn't make sense in the context of a deployed application.  If you imagine an application packaged as a self-contained executable JAR, your classpath essentially becomes your JRE folder + your JAR.  How would you be able to write to a file inside the JAR?

Best bet is to choose a folder somewhere on your file system and log to that.  I usually use the same location where I put my JAR file, or use a /var/log/... folder to log to.  If it is something only temporary, then I would log it to /tmp, but be careful with that as /tmp can sometimes have cleanup jobs that conflict with your logging settings.